# Validation error with JotForm template

Tags: javascript, wordpress, validation

A client sent me a form template they had created using https://jotform.com to implement on their WordPress site. The form template is supposed to hide part of the form until the user clicks the <kbd>next</kbd> button. At which point a script is supposed to validate all of the input fields the user has presumably filled out and then display the rest of the form. While I have successfully managed to get the form to display the next part of the form when the user clicks <kbd>next</kbd>, it fails to validate the input fields.

It's kind of difficult to explain without a huge block of text so it is probably easier to show you:

The original working template that the customer sent me:
<del>http://www.loftist.com/jotform/List_Your_Loft.html</del>

The problem child:
<del>http://www.loftist.com/?page_id=78</del>

If you just click on one of the input fields and then click elsewhere on the page, the input fields successfully return a validation error message and prevent the user from clicking on the <kbd>next</kbd> button. However, if you simply click on the <kbd>next</kbd> button than the next set of fields get displayed.

Any thoughts? What am I doing wrong here? Im convinced this must be a really simple problem but Im not sure what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem. Your first link, the original template, works for me with all the validations in place. The problem child on the second link is not a jotform form, and it doesn't have any paging stuff.

Do you mean jotform on your first web page is not working correctly? What does this have to do with the second form on your second link?

Comment: Sorry I hadn't noticed that the plugin had reverted to its default template. The JotForm is restored -